# Missing Integration Services Catalog in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 standard edition installed. I access remote to the server where SQL Server is installed. The option of the integration services catalog is missing under the database connection.

I did check the followings

- I have the role sysadmin when I log in SQL Server
- The service of integration services is installed and running.
- The installation of the management studio is complete
- I am missing the Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services when I run the `Dcomcnfg.exe` under Services, Computers, My Computer, and DCOM Config. Weird I am missing this. I wanted to find this to give appropriate permissions, but can't since the node is not there.

Any ideas? Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're using SSMS 2008. The Integration Services Catalog was introduced with SQL Server 2012. The older client doesn't know that's a "thing."

I prefer to manage servers with the latest and greatest version of SSMS which is now a free download.

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Choose "MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe"

For clarification

### Integration Services Catalog

[image: Integration Services Catalog]

### Integration Services Object Explorer

[image: Integration Services Object Explorer]

Comment: So how do I deploy the packages I have in SSMS?

Comment: Just to ensure we're talking the same thing, are you trying to deploy packages to the Integration Services Catalog or are you asking about Integration Services Object Explorer? For the packages you have, are they 2008 based or 2012? What server version are you attempting to deploy to?

Comment: I am talking about Integration services catalog. The server to deploy is 2008 r2 sp3

Comment: The integration Services Catalog was introduced with 2012. It is not available for 2008

Comment: I understand this. But my question is then, whats the alternative to deploy for 2008 in the management studio?

Comment: Deploy what? An SSIS package created under VS 2008?

Comment: mmm...good question. The package format version is 8. Does that help to answer the question.?

Comment: PackageFormatVersion 3 = 2008; 6 = 2012; 8 = 2014 Downgrading packages isn't an available option. Looks like you have nothing you *can* deploy. Sorry about that

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, Integration Server Catalog is invisible
This is my solution:

1. Check your installation edition of SQL Server.
   How to check? right click on the node of (SQL Server...) on SSMS - click properties - in "general" check the "product" name.

If you still use "SQL Server Developer Edition", some features will not available.
the solution is download **SQL Server Enterprise Edition**.

I have no idea for Standard Edition, but maybe you can also use Enterprise Edition.
This is link for download : [download SQL Server 2014](http://techconics.blogspot.co.id/2015/09/download-microsoft-sql-server-2014-with.html)

2. Click setup.exe to install and choose New SQL Server Stand-alone Installation select the feature you need. I think you can also select Integration Services in Feature Selection.. then fill the instance name and instance ID. continue the installation process until complete.
3. Open SQL Server Management Studio. Database Engine connection -> Server Name: (Server Name) / (Instance ID)
4. You will see the Integration Server Catalog. In the picture bellow, you can compare the display between SQL Server Developer Edition (above) & SQL Server Enterprise Edition (bottom with instance name).

I hope it can help..

Final result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and i have installed SSMS 17.0 and now i am able to create the SSISDB catalog with encryption password.

It's working as expected.